# Outputting to NMEA device using Python and SpiDev

Tags: python, spi

Using the `spi.xfer2()` function, I'd like to transmit a sentence to a device in NMEA format from my raspberry pi, which has some transducers connected to it for boating purposes. 
Here is the general form of the sentence I'd like to transmit:

```
'$--VHW,,T,,M,5.0,N,10.0,K*hh'
```

Is there a way to convert this string to the format required for this function? Is there another function I should use to output this data to our device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the interface description for your transducers. They will have a very special specification for how to address them over the SPI lines. 
Frequency, timing, polarity, to name few, and then mainly the SPI register format. There is no general solution.

Typically, if you want to transmit one payload byte, you transmit 12 or 16 bit over SPI, where the additional bits contain control information.

Here's how I did a transmission to a DA converter (it's reading, not writing, but thats not important):

```
  self.spi.cshigh=False
  self.spi.max_speed_hz=500000
  self.spi.mode=0
  self.spi.bits_per_word=8

  self.spi.open(0,0)

  for i in range(len(values)):
    xferWord = [0x01,0x80,0x00]#single ended, channel 0
    self.spi.xfer(xferWord)
    values[i]  = (0x03 & xferWord[1])<<8
    values[i] |= (0xff & xferWord[2])
    time.sleep(0.01)
  self.spi.close()
```